# How can bookmarks file be synced if it's not constantly reloaded?

Tags: bookmarks, load

If I create a bookmark on one platform, then try to use that bookmark on another platform, and if the bookmarks file isn't reloaded, then that new bookmark  isn't available.

How can I make sure my bookmark file gets reloaded when it's externally changed?

Comment: You also need to save your bookmarks file after creating the bookmark on the other platform, and before loading it on the first platform.

Comment: This really is no different from dealing with any other file between platforms - and even between Emacs sessions on the same platform. If you change a file buffer in one Emacs session then it needs to be saved there and then reloaded (or just revisited, if not Lisp code) in the other session.

Answer (score 1):

```
(add-hook 'lisp-data-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (when (or (string= (buffer-name) "bookmarks")
              (your-own-test-to-identify-reloadable-file)
      (auto-revert-mode))))
```

Comment: Good use of `lisp-data-mode-hook` (new for Emacs 29). But the buffer name won't necessarily be `bookmarks`. It could be anything at all. Better to use some other test. Maybe check some text in the file header, such as `Emacs Bookmark Format Version`.

Comment: @Drew Good point, handled.

Answer (score 1):

`auto-revert-mode` works well for cases where the file is visited by
emacs, but that is not the case here, so you could use the `filenotify` api instead:

```
(file-notify-add-watch bookmark-default-file '(change)
                       (lambda (ev)
                         (bookmark-load bookmark-default-file)))
```